# Hide iAd banner when no ads are available

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, iad

This is a Phonegap app. I am completely lost here, please help.
I followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitekickr.com/blog/phonegap-cordova-iad-integration/) to the t.

Here is my MainViewController.m:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


    if([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ==
       UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
       [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation ==
       UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    }
    else {
        adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
    }


    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = adFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];

    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fast answer:
What you need to do is conform to the ADBannerViewDelegate protocol and hide the ad when it fails to receive an ad.

Step by step version:

In that method you listed, you'll want to also include `adView.delegate = self`.

In MainViewController.h, where it says `@interface MainViewController : UIViewController`, you want to add `<ADBannerViewDelegate>` after, like this:

`@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>`. If there is already something in <  > there, just add a comma and add ADBannerViewDelegate.

Back in the MainViewController.m, add these methods:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
   adView.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
   adView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this worked =) other than before the ad loads the banner is still there. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, just add `adView.hidden = YES;` to your original method and it will hide it until an ad is loaded

Comment: Thank you works perfect now =)Do you have any tips on how to get the ad to stop overlapping my .html content?